# NginX website to listen on both port 80 and port 8080

Tags: nginx, debian

I  have a recent installation of NginX on a Raspberry Pi.  In the sites-available/myserver I have the following:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
#    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
...
```

I want to have this server listening on both port 80 and 8080,  but when I uncomment the Listen 8080 line above and restart NginX, the browser request times out. Port 80 requests work fine.

If I change the default_server line to 8080, then browser requests using :8080 also fail.

What am I doing wrong?....RDL

Comment: check firewalls

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb user error, I forgot to update IPTables for port 8080....RDK